# Upload XSD elements in a List

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2012, xsd

I am Working on Visual-studio 2012 in C#.
I have a xsd file abc.xsd as mentioned below.
I want to add its element names(Class and Place here) in a List.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="DocumentElement" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
  <xs:element name="DocumentElement" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="PositionMaster">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:all>

             <xs:element name="Class" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
             <xs:element name="Place" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />

            </xs:all>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Code written is below

```
List listData = new List();
XmlDocument xslDoc = new XmlDocument();
xslDoc.Load(abc.xsd);
XmlNamespaceManager nsMgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xslDoc.NameTable);
nsMgr.AddNamespace("xsl", "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform");
```

What should i write further so that my list contains these xsd elements? These elements may vary in number.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
using System.Xml.Linq;

XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\abc.xsd");
var t = xDoc.Descendants().Elements().Attributes().Where(x => x.Name == "name");
```

You can add more to the where condition to filter out the results as you need